# what a bug of apk may cause android reboot

Tags: android, apk

my app is drawing some images on surfaceview ,and have a certain probability cause android system reboot.I have pull the file "/proc/last_kmsg" out, may this be a bug of android system? The device is Samsung T805c.
Here is the last_kmsg log:

```
[ 5968.925578] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] ---------[ cut here ]------------
[ 5968.925738] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] kernel BUG at drivers/media/video/exynos/fimg2d/fimg2d_drv.c:208!
[ 5968.925997] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] Internal error: Oops - BUG: 0 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[ 5968.926240] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] CPU: 0    Not tainted  (3.4.39-6095882 #1)
[ 5968.926460] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] PC is at fimg2d_sysmmu_fault_handler+0x78/0x10c
[ 5968.926631] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] LR is at console_unlock+0x204/0x250
[ 5968.926830] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] pc : [<c048c658>]    lr : 
[<c003baec>]    psr: 600f0193
[ 5968.926901] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] sp : db3cbc08  ip : db3cba80  fp : db3cbc2c
[ 5968.927168] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] r10: 8ff9b000  r9 : c09072f8  r8 : 00000000
[ 5968.927362] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] r7 : deaf8790  r6 : d76d0000  r5 : c0b8cf38  r4 : c0c434dc
[ 5968.927572] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] r3 : 00000000  r2 : c0b5c554  r1 : 800f0193  r0 : 00000068
[ 5968.927774] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] Flags: nZCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[ 5968.927989] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 376d006a  DAC: 00000015
[ 5968.928129] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] CPU 0 / CLUSTER 0
[ 5968.928308] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] DFSR: 00000021, ADFSR: 00000000, IFSR: 00000007, AIFSR: 00000000
[ 5968.928520] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] CPUMERRSR: 00000000_00000000, L2MERRSR: 00000000_00000000
[ 5968.928730] I[B0: com.example.test:  7576] CPUFREQ: 900000 KHz
```

Answer (score 0):

Is difficult to find the cause. Maybe the problem is something linked to your graphical adapter.

Try that in your manifest (put it inside

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot，it's very helpful，but I still meet this occasionally